# How to make a flexbox container horizontally scrollable

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this **HTML** and **CSS**

```css
#container{
  border:1px solid red;
  display:flex;
  overflow:auto;
}
.item{
    border:1px solid green;
    margin:5px;
    width:700px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div class="item">
  ...
</div>
<div class="item">
  ...
</div>
....
<!-- more items -->
</div>
```

The width of `.item` is not being changed by the `width` property.

If I set `min-width on` .item` then it's working.

```
.item{
    border:1px solid green;
    margin:5px;
    width:700px;
    min-width:300px;
}
```

Is there any other way to make the flex container scrollable?

Check out the pen https://codepen.io/ats99/pen/JjEzRyV?editors=1100

Comment: it works so what is wrong with what you have currently

Comment: As i am learning, so i would like to try the best way to achieve something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `flex-shrink: 0` to your flexbox children. It will prevent the default flexbox behavior, which tries to fit your children in it by squeezing them.

Comment: Why this is the best way to do?

Comment: Updated the answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the same effect without using `min-width` then you can just apply `flex: 0 0 auto` to `.item`.

Comment: Thanks,for the asnwer